# Read without -r will mangle backslashes

Tags: bash, scripts, ubuntu-mate

```
cd $Script_Dir
clear
read -p "Enter name of script to run shellcheck on. -> " n1
shellcheck "$n1" 

In shellchk.sh line 10:
read -p "Enter name of script to run shellcheck on. -> " n1
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.
```

Why is it saying that?
I would never use a back slash in a file name.

If I use

```
read -r "Enter name of script to run shellcheck on. -> " n1

/home/andy/bin/nshellchk.sh: line 11: read: `Enter name of script to run shellcheck on. -> ': not a valid identifier
: : openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Should always include the `-r` just as convention. It's not mandatory. Check the wiki [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162). Another [ref](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2162).

Comment: @CG3 See my edited question when I use -r.

Comment: Your question is obscure. It might be that the first chapter in your code block is content of a file called shellchk.sh and then you run that script and type its own name to get the shellcheck output. You could formulate your question more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` is bash builtin. `help read` tells

> -r    do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

`shellcheck` warns about using `read` without `-r` because `read` would not read the backslashes as is then. If you do not need to enable backslash function, use `-r`. `shellcheck` does not know if you want to use backlashes in your file names or not.

You have to use `-p` if you want `read` to display the prompt text. So you might want to use

```
read -r -p "Enter name of script to run shellcheck on. -> " n1
```